# Cannot login a webpage using Python

Tags: python, request, web-scraping, session-cookies

I have tried many ways to login a webpage within Python but from the returning values it seems not working. Could any one help? Here are my trials:

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'companyName': mycompanyname,
    'username': myusername,
    'password': mypassword }

with session() as c:
    c.post(url_main, data=payload)
    request = c.get(url_hidden)
    print request.headers
    print request.text
```

This returns messages before I logged in actually.

```
import urllib2, cookielib
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'companyName':mycompanyname,'username' : myusername, 'password' : mypassword})
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.open(url_main, login_data)
myfile = opener.open(url_hidden)

output = open('t1.txt', 'w')
output.write(myfile.read())
output.close()
```

Again, what's noted in the t1.txt is also the information before I logged in.

I have checked the source code of the webpage, and it is like:

```
<DIV class=labelFix><LABEL for=companyName><STRONG>Company</STRONG>:</LABEL></DIV>
<DIV class=fieldFix><INPUT tabIndex=1 id=companyName size=8 name=companyName dpieagent_iecontroltype="2"> </DIV><BR>
<DIV class=labelFix><LABEL for=username><STRONG>Username</STRONG>:</LABEL></DIV>
<DIV class=fieldFix><INPUT tabIndex=2 id=username size=8 name=username dpieagent_iecontroltype="2"> </DIV><BR>
<DIV class=labelFix><LABEL for=password><STRONG>Password</STRONG>:</LABEL></DIV>
<DIV class=fieldFix><INPUT tabIndex=3 id=password maxLength=16 size=8 type=password name=password dpieagent_iecontroltype="3"> <INPUT id=status type=hidden name=status> </DIV><BR>
<DIV class=searchBtnFix><INPUT tabIndex=4 id=btnLogin class=searchBtn type=submit value=Log-on name=submit> <INPUT onclick="location.href='logout.asp?redir=/default.asp?action=article&ID=1'" tabIndex=5 id=btnLogout class=searchBtn type=button value=Log-out name=button> 
<P style="PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 84px"><A href="/useofcookies"><FONT size=1>Use of cookies</FONT></A></P></DIV></FORM></TD>
<TD class=container1b vAlign=top>
```

So the login information should be indeed 'companyName', 'username' and 'password' right? If I log in on the website I have to click on a button 'log on' - but I cannot do it in Python.